# Is there something wrong with my json structure?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'll have my PHP like so:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#20 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Indie"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#21 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Cult-classic"
  }
}
```

Then json_encode it which results in this:

```
0: {name:Indie}
name: "Indie"
1: {name:Cult-classic}
name: "Cult-classic"
```

So why is this getting undefined (it's actually just traversing every character treating the structure as a string.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tagged.length; i++) {
    alert(tagged[i].name);
}
```

Update:

```
$.post('/host/tags/item_tags/' + movieId,
    function(tagged) {
        alert(tagged);
        for(var i = 0; i < tagged.length; i++) {
            alert(tagged[i]);
        }
});
```

Comment: What's the json output? Can you post it please?

Comment: if you do `alert(tagged[i]);` what do you get

Comment: Add more code, how You are using it, and post the complete **JSON** output, 'coz one You pasted is invalid.

Comment: @mgraph gives 1 char each iteration [ then { then " etc

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski alert(tagged); gets what Brad the format Brad answered in

Comment: `tagged` is a string containing your JSON data. You have to parse it into a JavaScript object or array first, or set the correct content header for jQuery to figure it out automatically, or pass `'json'` as forth (third) parameter to `$.post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, I doubt `json_encode()` is giving you that kind of broken output.  This is the appropriate output:

```
[
    {"name":"Indie"},
    {"name":"Cult-classic"}
]
```

So to answer your question, yes, there is something wrong with your output.  You can validate your JSON at:  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Actually that's what alert(tagged) yields, chrome dev had it without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Tranverse along the json data with `.each()` instead

```
function(tagged) {        
    $.each(tagged, function(k,v) {
       alert(v);
    });
}
```